# passing images through props: getting "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" and a white screen

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I was wondering can you pass the path to an image through props

```
import './App.css';
import panda from "./panda.jpg";

function Welcome(props)
{
  return (
   <img src ={require (props.test)} alt={"why no work"}/>);
}

function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        
        <Welcome  test = {panda}/>
     
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I know that

```
 <img src ={require ("./panda.jpg")} alt={"why no work"}/>);
```

works.

I'm trying to a few containers with different image's in it and wondering is there a easier way of doing this